# VBA Internet Explorer - Object variables disappear

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to learn web scraping with VBA and i am running into an issue in the most basic first step.

The problem (I think) is that after IEObject.Navigate is performed, all the variables of IEObject dissapear. So I get the error

> "Run-time error '426': The remote server machine does not exist or is
>   unavailable"

on line 8. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
Sub VBAWeb()

Dim IEObject As InternetExplorer
Set IEObject = New InternetExplorer
IEObject.Visible = True
IEObject.Navigate URL:="https://google.com"

Do While IEObject.Busy = True Or IEObject.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Loop

Debug.Print IEObject.LocationURL

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the above code exactly as you have it in excel? It works fine for me.

Comment: Try changing `IEObject.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE` to `IEObject.ReadyState <> 4`.

Comment: Showed code works for me as well. Do you use google.com also in your tests? If not, tell us clearly what you try to do

Comment: The above code is exactly what I am running.
Changing to {IEObject.ReadyState <> 4} does not work.
I have tried som different url:s.
Thank you guys but no dice. Probably something to do with non-admin access of the pc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to run code below on your side may help to fix the issue.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True

    URL = "https://www.microsoft.com"

    IE.Navigate URL

    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop  
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   

    Debug.Print IE.LocationURL

    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

You can see that the IE object was created differently. Also, the loop is a little bit different.

Comment: It is not working. The object IE still has no variables after navigating to the URL. Thanks though!

Comment: I suggest you for testing purposes, try to lower down the security levels in IE security zones and check and verify that script related options are enabled. Then try to run the code to see the result.